# JQuery custom function with multiple parameter doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I tried to create JQUERY to append div to existing div

```
(function($){
  $.fn.alertme=function(){
    var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.alertme.defaults, options );
    $divContent =$('<div></div>').appendTo(opts.container);
    $divContent.prop('class','divclass');
  };

  $.fn.alertme.defaults = {
    container: "body",
    background: "yellow"
  };
})(jQuery);
```

this is how i called it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#testbutton').on('click',function(){
    $.alertme(
      {container : '#target'}
    );
  });
});
```

its return error options in not define

please help me guys what i do wrong here

Comment: You can use `$("#target").alertme()` to calling function and use `this` instead of `opts.container` in function defintion

Comment: yes, but i need to fire the plugin from dynamic content

Comment: `$("#target").` is selector and you can select any element you want

Comment: i need to call it with button click,

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/ytfzmup1/

Comment: i need to call it from '#target', that create after document ready using append like $('#otherbutton').on('click',function(){$('<div ID="target">test</div>').appendTo($('Body')), the div#target not predefine

Answer (score 3):

Pass options as argument.

```
(function($){
  $.extend({
    alertme: function(options){
      var defaults = {
        container: "body",
        background: "yellow"
      };
      var opts = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
      $divContent =$(opts.container).append('<div>abc</div>');
      $divContent.prop('class','divclass');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```